# Add CSS to specific class after page is already loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I got this multi step contact form and I want to add a class to a specific div depending on which step of the form I am.

The current step is specified with the class ".current".
So as you can see, step 1 of my form is currently active (default on page load).

```
<ul class="multi-step-list">
   <li class="step-1 current">Name</li>
   <li class="step-2">Address</li>
   <li class="step-3">Message</li>
   <li class="step-4">Send</li>
</ul>
```

Now I have a div where I want to add a class, when step 2 is active with the class ".current"
Depending on the step I am, ".current" switches automatically to my current step.

So when step 2 is active, I want to add the class ".myClass" to my div "myDiv".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    if($('li.step-2').hasClass('current')) {
        $('div.myDiv').toggleClass('myClass');
    }
});
```

I know I am wrong here because that would only take effect on page load and step 2 is pre-selected.
".myClass" should only appear when ".step-2" has class ".current" and when I switch to e.g. step 3, the class must disappear.

I hope I can get some advice here.

Comment: What is the "multi step contact form" you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call an event on just the one you click, and remove the class from all siblings except the one you're clicking (and add it to that one). And base the same logic to the div you want to change. Like so

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".step").each(function() {
         $(this).click(function(e) {
     var step2 = 'two';
     $(this).addClass("active-step").siblings().removeClass("active-step");
     if (e.target.id == step2) {
      $(".myDiv").addClass("something");
     } else {
     $(".myDiv").removeClass("something");
     }
    });
});

});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 2rem;
}

li {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background: darkorchid;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.active-step {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  background: teal;
}

.myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: goldenrod;
}

.something {
  background: royalblue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multi-step-list">
   <li class="step step-1 current">Name</li>
   <li class="step step-2" id="two">Address</li>
   <li class="step step-3">Message</li>
   <li class="step step-4">Send</li>
</ul>

<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle the `.myClass` *only* when the form changes to a specific step, you should set the `.myClass` in the same function where you change the form step.

So instead of setting `.myClass` in `$(document).ready()` -callback, set it in the function (that you did not include in your question), that is used to switch the form step. And in that function check if the step to switch to is "2", then set `.myClass` on the div. Otherwise remove the `.myClass` from the div.